# Version control for android project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, version-control

I am now using mac os X 10.9.1. My team use windows 7 . I want to use version control in my project using eclipse. Can I set up my mac as a version control server without using internet? Which version control system is easy to use and best for my project ?

Comment: If you install the free XCode from Apple it includes both git and subversion (svn).

Answer (score 0):

I think GIT is good choice for you

Answer (score 0):

Try GIT. you will get a installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/) or you can install it through macports `$ sudo port install git-core +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb` . you can find configuration documents from [GIT](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) website.
`

Comment: Is git can install not server version of mac? Can I setup git server on mac?

Comment: yes. you can set up Git server if needed. if you are looking for only a client then its already available with xcode.

Comment: Can you please give me reference tutorial for Git Server on mac (Not Server version os).

Comment: Try this http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/installing-gitlab-on-mac-os-x-and-mac-os-x-server/